# CLion not running in Terminal

Tags: c, clion, jetbrains-ide

There's this bug with the placement of certain characters in the embedded terminal in CLion (the Run tab that pops up when you click the Run button), and I figured out that if I changed the terminal in CLion, that wouldn't happen. I changed the terminal to cmder, and it is all working now, except one thing: I can't figure out how to make CLion run the program to that terminal.

I tried changing the configuration, but all it did on run was open cmder but not execute the program (I had to run it manually, by writing the file name).

I wonder, what's the way to fix this, and make CLion directly run C programs on the terminal, instead of the Run tab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The CLion run configuration always runs in the integreted run window. That is not a terminal emulator, and it cannot be changed so that it runs in an actual terminal emulator (like cmder).

Your best bet is to try to fix the "character placement" in the run window. Maybe ask a different question where you explain the issue, or if it's a clear bug, [file a bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP) for it.

Comment: In fact, I did already file that bug report. There's a workaround to the problem, apparently, but it just creates another even more annoying bug.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-19357