# Use external terminal window instead of the integrated one

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I don't want my input/output to appear in the integrated Terminal, I want IntelliJ to open and use a new cmd.exe window each time I execute the program. Is that possible?

**Edit:** For clarification, since apparently I was using wrong terminology (sorry about that): By 'integrated terminal' I meant the 'Run' window (where all the System.out.print stuff goes).

So basically I want my program's output to not be shown inside this Run window, but rather inside a new terminal window (cmd.exe preferably), just like if you would start your programs from the terminal itself.

Is that still possible? Because I think it was at one point in the past. And if not, why?

Comment: Please describe the steps when IDE opens the integrated terminal for you.

Comment: @Andrey Well what steps can I describe? The integrated terminal opens normally. But I don't want that. I want a cmd.exe window to be opened.

Comment: @TPRammus To clarify the situation, please record small screencast that would illustrate the issue (some simple dummy project; should show whole IDE window). **P.S.** Do you mean the actual "terminal" or the "Run" window, which is different? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61484213/783119

Comment: @LazyOne First of all, thank you guys for your time.
Well you are right, I didn't mean the actual terminal, but the Run window (where all the System.out.print stuff goes), I assumed it would also be called a terminal, sorry about that.
And there is no "issue" in that sense, everything works as intended by JetBrains, I just want to change this behaviour so that the program's output ends up in a new terminal window, rather than the integrated Run window of IntelliJ.