# How to launch Windows Terminal from PyCharm/JetBrains IDE

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I wish to launch the new program offered in Windows 10 i.e. [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal) (not cmd) when I press the Run button in JetBrains PyCharm IDE. Please let me know how to do that.

[image: PyCharm Run Button]

Comment: I'm not using PyCharm myself (using another JetBrains IDE) .. but can you please show a screenshot of the "cmd" that you are getting when you clicking the Run button? I just have a feeling that it's not actual terminal but normal Run toolwindow...

Comment: Yes it is normal toolwindow .... I want  Any Jetbrains IDE to open "Windows New Terminal" as a separate popup and run some commands in it ..... Is there any plugin in marketplace that can add a tool in toolbar that can popup new terminal and run some script inside it like "Native Terminal" plugin (but it only supports only cmd and does not allow to have any custom script inside it)

Comment: Well .. you can set up an External Tool and run any predefined commands this way. It can then be added to a toolbar. But you won't be able to link that to a Run/Debug buttons (because they just run your script and simply redirect the output; that's not terminal at all -- e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61484213/783119)

Comment: Okay may be "External Tool" is what will suffice for me ...